# SPARQL Query - WHERE ignoing clause? (dbpedia)

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

This is supposed to bring back a list of trees, and optional a thumbnail picture.

By 'trees' I mean the green, leafy plants:

```
PREFIX gold: <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * { 
?tree a dbo:Plant;
          gold:hypernym dbr:Tree.
OPTIONAL { ?tree dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail }
}
```

Click here to run that [SPARQL](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20gold%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Flinguistics%2Fgold%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Ftree%20a%20dbo%3APlant%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gold%3Ahypernym%20dbr%3ATree.%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Ftree%20dbo%3Athumbnail%20%3Fthumbnail%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=10000&signal_void=on) above.

It mostly works: but it also brings back this type of Tree:

https://dbpedia.org/page/M-ary_tree

Oddly: the data isn't apparently labelled as being a 'dbo:Plant' though?

Is there something else going on here? (like it being 'sameAs' or something? I notice the result actually says 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/K-ary_tree', but this lands on 'M-aray').

Comment: as you already recognized, putting a URI in the browser sometimes leads to a redirected entity in DBpedia. That means, you better have to check the data in the triplestore: `SELECT * {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/K-ary_tree> ?p ?o}` - and indeed, that shows up the type `dbo:Plant`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [uninformeduser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser) - who provided the explanation in the comments.
I can confirm the explanation was correct.

The page does indeed redirect with a [HTTP-301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) :

```bash
> export URL=https://dbpedia.org/page/K-ary_tree
> curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" $URL 
301> 
> curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code} : %{url_effective}" $URL --location 
200 : https://dbpedia.org/page/M-ary_tree>
```

And the provided SPARQL does show the entry is (incorrectly) classified as a plant:

```
# Returns 'true'
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
ASK { dbr:K-ary_tree a dbo:Plant}
```

[Run SPARQL1](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0AASK+%7B+dbr%3AK-ary_tree+a+dbo%3APlant%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=10000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on)

I'm still a little confused about this behaviour - since the redirect seems to be invisible at the [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) level to the end-user - the redirect just seems to happen. (Unless I'm missing some connection somewhere else).

So asking whether 'K-Array' is a plant yields yes, but the original 'M-Array' is false.

```
# Returns 'false'
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
ASK { dbr:M-ary_tree a dbo:Plant }
```

[Run SPARQL2](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0AASK+%7B+dbr%3AM-ary_tree+a+dbo%3APlant+%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=10000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on):